# How to do a template specialization with multiple arguments (when the type of one of them is known)

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Here's the template for a class

```
 template <typename T, unsigned int size>
 class Foo { 
       T myarray[size];
       //other code (doesn't matter for the example)
 }
```

and I want to do a template specialization for it. For example, I have defined `class Bar`. So I want to make a specialization for `class Bar`, but I want to keep `unsigned int size`. How do I do that?

```
template <>
class Foo<Bar, unsigned int> {   //throws error "type name not allowed" for unsigned int
      Bar myarray[size];
      //other code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called partial template specialization:

```
template<unsigned int size>
class Foo<Bar, size> {

    Bar myarray[size];
};
```